# How should I understand the といこう in お手並み拝見といこうかしら

Tags: grammar

> 『ええ、もちろん。お手並み拝見**といこう**かしら』

Hi. How should I understand the といこう? I know it comes from といく. What does it mean? And what is this grammar phenomenon of 「と+いく」?